# Android Camera Preview Starting From Service

Tags: android, camera, background-process, preview

I used [this code example](https://github.com/chatea/ServiceCamera) to capture videos in background.

Unfortunately, my attempts to create a camera preview failed.
The preview in my activity crashes when the background-capture-process is started and vice versa.

Any ideas, how to avoid a those crashes?

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: It says: E/Camera: Error 2